# Grouping results within XML element with inner joins

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I am trying to understand how I can combine LINQ-to-XML and LINQ-to-SQL queries, and perform a join.

Specifically, I have an SQL table that contains city, county, and state information, and I am able to query it with LINQ to SQL, but in the same query, I would like to join SQL rows that have the same state and/or county, and generate an XML as part of the output.

Here is approximately what my table looks like:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦═══════╗
║ IDX ║     CITY     ║   COUNTY       ║ STATE ║ 
╠═════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬═══════╣
║  1  ║ YAKUTAT      ║ ALEUTIANS EAST ║ AK    ║
║  2  ║ city-1       ║ ALEUTIANS EAST ║ AK    ║
║  3  ║ city-2       ║ ALEUTIANS EAST ║ AK    ║
║  4  ║ city-3       ║ ALEUTIANS WEST ║ AK    ║
║  5  ║ city-4       ║ ALEUTIANS WEST ║ AK    ║
║  6  ║ city-5       ║ ALEUTIANS WEST ║ AK    ║
║  7  ║ xyz          ║ ANCHORAGE      ║ AK    ║
║  8  ║ abc          ║ BETHEL         ║ AK    ║
║  9  ║ lmnop        ║ WYOMING        ║ NY    ║
║  10 ║ pqrst        ║ WARSAW         ║ NY    ║
║  11 ║ defg         ║ WARSAW         ║ NY    ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩═══════╝
```

And this is what I would like my XML output to look like.  I would like the join to group all cities with the same county as nodes under the same county node, and then group all counties in a state as child nodes of the state node.

```
<State>AK</State>
  <County>ALEUTIANS EAST</County>
    <City>YAKUTAT</City>
    <City>city-1</City>
    <City>city-2</City>
  <County>ALEUTIANS WEST</County>
    <City>city-3</City>
    <City>city-4</City>
    <City>city-5</City>   
  <County>ANCHORAGE</County>
    <City>xyz</City>
  <County>BETHEL</County>
    <City>abc</City>
<State>NY</State>
  <County>WYOMING</County>
    <City>lmnop</City>
  <County>WARSAW</County>
    <City>pqrst</City>
    <City>defg</City>
```

I do have this partially working, I am able to successfully select rows from my database and I am able to write the output as an XML, but I cannot get the city and county data nested as child nodes of the state, and I am missing the join part and it is not clear how to do this.

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("States",
   (from states in state.Database 
    select new XElement(new XElement("State",states.State),
           new XElelment("County",states.County),
           new XElelment("City",state.City))));

xDoc.Save("C:\\states.xml")
```

And this is the output that I am getting.  As you can see, I am getting a complete listing of all of the city, states, and counties in my database without an hierarchy.

```
<State>AK</State>
<County>ALEUTIANS EAST</County>
<City>YAKUTAT</City>
<State>AK</State>
<County>ALEUTIANS EAST</County>
<City>city-1</City>
<State>AK</State>
<County>ALEUTIANS EAST</County>
<City>city-2</City>
<State>AK</State>
<County>ALEUTIANS WEST</County>
<City>city-3</City>
<State>AK</State>
<County>ALEUTIANS WEST</County>
<City>city-4</City>
....and so on..
```

Comment: ok i wonder why the moderators closed this question, do u think i would waste my time asking a rhetorical question after signing up...i have used the data from a different post that is only because the data concerned with my project has perosnal details....

Comment: @user2141957 It was not moderators who closed your question, but 5 members of the community.  The most likely reason it was closed was because you really didn't ask a question, or at least the way you wrote the question, it is very difficult to figure out what you are asking.  I think your questions might be salvageable, but you need to provide some clarification.  Specifically, what is `state`?  Is it a collection?  You reference an SQL, but there is no indication how that is coming into play.

Comment: @user2141957 one suggestion I would make is read this blog entry: [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).  It is a very good article written by one of our highest ranking members on how to write a good question to get good answers.  It is very helpful

Comment: @psubsee2003: i tried to put the data in a tabular form, but the formatting tags were not limited and hence it appeared like a paragraph instead of a table, i tried HTML , i must have wasted like 30 mins trying to figure the best way to type my question here, and finally 5 guys close my post thinking i was wasting my time here.ugggghhhh

Comment: @psubsee2003 but to answer your question state was column from the table.so was county and city.

Comment: @user2141957 I am trying to help so please do not take this the wrong way, but it wasn't closed because people thought you were wasting your time, it was closed because they thought you were wasting everyone else's time.  Questions need to be clear, well supported, and well researched.  When someone has to spend 15 minutes reading the question to figure out what is being asked, or the question is missing key information, there is a good chance it will be closed.  In general, there is a learning curve on how to ask good questions here, and it can take a while to figure it out

Comment: @user2141957 back to your question... I have limited familiarity with SQL, especially in representing databases in C#, so I am trying to understand the `state` object (from this line in the code: `from states in state.Database`).  What type of C# object is `state`?  Is it a collection of objects?  Or is it literally your database that you are trying to query with LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @user2141957 I have tried to update your question as best as I could.  Please let me know if I misinterpreted or misunderstood anything and feel free to edit it again.  However, note the edits that were performed earlier... please do not try to address specific individuals in the question or add "Please help me I am new" type commentary.  Just keep to with the facts, the code, and the issues you are having, plus any supporting data.

Comment: @user2141957 in everything, I failed to notice that your example XML output looks nothing like what I thought you were describing.  You have no hierarchy in that example, it is just a list of nodes.  Are you sure that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You really have several separate problems, first is you are not able to generate a hierarchical XML file (assuming that I am understanding your original intent before I edited your question).  In fact your example XML isn't even hierarchical to begin with as you are closing tags before nested the intended child tags underneath it.  Indenting like you are doing is not creating any kind of child node, just makes it look like.

This is what I think you want your XML to look like:

```
<State>AK
  <County>ALEUTIANS EAST
    <City>YAKUTAT</city>
    <City>city-1</city>
  </County>
</State>
```

But mixing simple types like strings with complex types like other nodes in the same node can be very confusing.  May I suggest a modification of the structure to use attributes, thus eliminating some of the confusing hierarchy.  A structure such as this would be more commonly acceptable:

```
<State name = "AK">
  <County name = "ALEUTIANS EAST">
    <City>YAKUTAT</city>
    <City>city-1</city>
  </County>
</State>
```

Generating a nested XML is simply a matter of arranging your `XElement` objects inside of each other

```
XElement stateElement = new XElement("State", new XAttribute("name", "AK"), 
                            new XElement("County", new XAttribute("name", "ALEUTIANS EAST"), 
                                new XElement("City", "YAKUTAT"), 
                                new XElement("City", "city-1")));
```

Will generate an XML with structure I suggested above.

The second part you are missing is the join.  Since everything is in the same table, you are actually looking for a group query as you want to combine child elements under a single common parent.

I am not an expect in LINQ-to-SQL, and the fact that there can be subtitle differences between the different flavors, I am not 100% certain that the syntax will be exactly right, but hopefully, if it is off, it will still get you pointed in the right direction.

*Please note that just because you are creating an XML file, this is not LINQ-to-XML, LINQ is about querying the source, not the output and since you are querying your database, this is LINQ-to-SQL*

```
var query = from states in state.Database 
            group states by new { states.State, states.County } into countyGroup
            group countyGroup by countyGroup.Key.State into stateGroup
            select new XElement("State", new XAttribute("name", stateGroup.Key),
                       stateGroup.Select(st => new XElement("County", new XAttribute("name", st.Key.County),
                       st.Select(city => new XElement("City", city.City)))));

var xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
                         new XElement("States", query.ToArray()));
```

The first group statement will group all of your database rows into groups based on a common County and State (it is necessary to include the state as if you exclude it cities within Orange, FL and Orange, CA will be grouped together.  The second group statement will then group your database rows further into common states.  You end up with a grouping (called `stateGroup` that consists of a collection of cities that in the same county, and counties that are grouped in the same city.

The select statement to break out that grouping into appropriate XML nodes gets very messy, but it is effectively writing out each of the groupings in order to get to where I think you want to go.

(you also missed the XML declaration when you were creating your `XDocument` in your question, so I have added that here).

Comment: thanks a bunch to give a newbie such a detailed explanation, you not only clarified my confusion about linq- xml but you re-framed my original question better.

Comment: @user2141957 but now you can see what the difference a well framed question can do... the question was reopened 5 minutes after i finished my initial edit.  You complained about spending 30 minutes on the question... but honestly, I usually spend at least that much time writing my own questions on the site.  It takes that long to get a good questions.

Comment: @user2141957 I don't normally do this on my own answers, but don't forget to upvote if you found it helpful, and check the answer mark if it solved the problem.